# Sequelize model loader import doesn't work on top level import but only works on function import

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

The question is little unclear as bug itself is unclear in its way.
The main question would be what are the possible cases which can lead to empty sequelize model loder.

`user.js`

```js
const db = require('../db/models');
async testFunc function(data){
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      try{
          let user = await db.User.findOne({where:{id:data.id}});
           resolve(user)
       }catch(error){reject(error)}
})
}
module.exports={
testFunc
}
```

This is snippet of module defined which works fine on its own. But let's say if its used in another module the db is not loaded so throws error db.User is undefined

`user.js`

```js
async testFunc function(data){
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      const db = require('../db/models');
      try{
          let user = await db.User.findOne({where:{id:data.id}});
           resolve(user)
       }catch(error){reject(error)}
})
}
module.exports={
testFunc
}
```

Current workaround is require model loader inside each function(there are other similar functions too).

Just throwing the question to know possible mistakes and to find the better approach.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think it's because of the relative path ```../db/models```. If you're using the function inside another module, are you sure that relative path to ```db/models``` would be the same as you've put here?

Comment: no path is okay, also it's working too if I execute the `testFunc(params);` with necessary params using `node user.js`

Answer (score 0):

You question seems to be pointing to how can you import modules Asyncronously insode promises:

1. **CommonJS**

The traditional and most common way to import modules is using the `CommonJS` syntax

```
const React = require('react');
```

2. **ECMA Script Modules**

Second way, which is gaining popularity, especially in React and Angular ecosystem, is the EcmaScript Modules:

```
import { <function> } from './index.js';
```

3. **Dynamic Import**

Third is [**Dynamic Import**](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import), which is what you need in your second example to dynamically load modules when do your DB related operations.

This is what you need in your second example. To dynamically load modules when do your DB related operation

```
async testFunc function(data){
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      const db = require('../db/models');
      import('./db/models').then(dialogBox => {
              let user = await db.User.findOne({where:{id:data.id}});
              resolve(user)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
              })
           })
```

The result of the DB Models is a Promise. Once the module is completely loaded, the Promise is fulfilled with it.

Comment: yes the issues should be somewhere around the imports and I am using CommonJs imports but i don't think the model loader at `../db/models/index.js` is async although the operation with the models are.

Comment: anyway, I can try async import. but how would you async import using commonJs style

Comment: CommonJS is obsolete in terms of new features. It is better to not use it in your projects https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5132#issuecomment-15432598

Comment: will read the throughly later, but currently nodejs don't support ecmaScript import without babel and other setup and also I think we are deviating from the question itself

Comment: You must be using node version <13. As far as the deviation from question goes, it depends on how you want to import modules which depends on how latest version of ECMASceipt is used in your project.